# Count number of times an account_ID is shared between groups in a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe, count, duplicates

I have a dataframe in R that has a large number of bank_account_IDs and Vendor_Codes. Bank_account_IDs should not be shared between Vendor_Codes, but sometimes a fraudulent vendor exists that shares another vendor's bank_account_ID.

I want to add a new field to the dataframe that provides a count for the number of times an account_ID exists with more than 1 Vendor_Code.

My sample dataframe is as follows:

```
bank_account_ID = c(a, b, c, a, a, d, e, f, b, c)

Vendor_Code = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)

df <-data.frame(a,b)
```

My ideal new dataframe should look something like this:

```
 bank_account_ID Vendor_Code duplicate_count
 a                 1             2
 b                 2             1
 c                 3             1
 a                 4             2
 a                 5             2 
 d                 6             0
 e                 7             0
 f                 8             0
 b                 9             1
 c                10             1
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

We can get the number of distinct elements with `n_distinct` grouped by the 'bank_account_ID' and subtract 1

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(bank_account_ID) %>%
  mutate(dupe_count = n_distinct(Vendor_Code)-1) %>%
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 10 x 4
#   bank_account_ID Vendor_Code duplicate_count dupe_count
#   <chr>                 <int>           <int>      <dbl>
# 1 a                         1               2          2
# 2 b                         2               1          1
# 3 c                         3               1          1
# 4 a                         4               2          2
# 5 a                         5               2          2
# 6 d                         6               0          0
# 7 e                         7               0          0
# 8 f                         8               0          0
# 9 b                         9               1          1
#10 c                        10               1          1
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(bank_account_ID = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "a", "d", 
"e", "f", "b", "c"), Vendor_Code = 1:10, duplicate_count = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```